# Semicolon or period?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons, periods

> Each conjunctive adverb has an individual *meaning; thus,* you should use whichever one fits the sense of the sentence you are writing.

[The source website](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/modulecs_fs.htm#:%7E:text=Two%20independent%20clauses%20can%20also,sentence%20with%20a%20semicolon%20alone.&text=Thus%2C%20it%20can%20separate%20two,a%20coordinating%20conjunction%20(FANBOYS).)

Can I write these independent sentences separately by replacing semicolon with dot?

Is it only about to show how sentences are very closely related? Because "thus" already links these two sentences and there's no need to use semicolon.

Comment: Yes you can. If you want a slightly longer pause than a semi-colon warrants, use a full stop (period).

Comment: If you want a slight *shorter* pause (more accurately, *no pause*), replace **semicolon THUS comma** with **SO** (no punctuation *required*, but you could precede that by a comma if you want).